# 403 for DocumentRoot outside of ServerRoot

Tags: apache, xampp

My Xampp on linux is set up like this

```
ServerRoot "/opt/lampp"
DocumentRoot "/home/webadmin/webroot"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory "/home/webadmin/webroot">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.php index.php3 index.php4
</IfModule>
...
```

This leads to a 403. However, when I change DocumentRoot to "/opt/lampp/htdocs", it works.

Already double checked that /home/webadmin/webroot is readable. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

ServerRoot must be a directory above the DocumentRoot, so if you really need to have document root at "/home/webadmin/webroot" you must set your ServerRoot to "/home/webadmin/webroot" at least... or something like "/home/webadmin"

Comment: Where did you get this? Can you point me to the manual that claims this restriction. AFAIK, ServerRoot is the directory for webserver executable/ logs/ scripts etc. and DocumentRoot is where the files are served from. The default lamp installation might put the latter inside the former but it is perfectly logical to separate them.